# How to run a task in background in windows

Tags: windows, nohup

I usually use nohup to run any task in background in linux

```
nohup python sss.py &
```

What is the similar command used to run a background task in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of? In Windows, there's [`start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx) which launches another command outside of your current CLI session. The down side is that the process isn't attached in any way to the window you launched it from so you don't get output sharing like you would in Linux.

An alternative to achieve this may be to use something like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) which gives you (most of) `bash` on Windows. (Update 2020: Windows 10 has [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) now. This allows you to run a good chunk of Linux on a Windows host.)

Comment: Would you know whether processes started asynchronously with `start` are stopped when the user signs off, when the screen is locked, or when the console is switched to a different user (i.e. ctrl-alt-del Switch User)?

Comment: @init_js You'd be better off asking that as a question on Superuser rather than as a comment on an old answer.

Comment: The answer's still valid, despite its age. I had asked a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/q/1340751/525084), but forgot to add a link to it!